# powershell to copy files and append foldername to copied files

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Iam trying to copy file "abc.txt" from daily folder under root folder. 
let say source folder paths and files looks like..

```
\\Server01\rootdir->01-01-20->abc.txt
\\Server01\rootdir->01-01-20->abc.txt
\\Server01\rootdir->01-01-20->Details->abc.txt
..
..
\\Server01\rootdir->10-25-20->Details->abc.txt
\\Server01\rootdir->11-15-20->abc.txt
\\Server01\rootdir->12-30-20->abc.txt           ---File existed in parent folder
\\Server01\rootdir->12-31-20->Details->abc.txt  ---File not in parent but in child
```

I want to copy abc.txt files from all these folders into one location. but while copying I need to append folder name to file like abc_01-01-20.txt. But there are chances that inside root->01-01-20 may contain child folder (**Details**) and it could have same the file name inside. so if file not existed in 01-01-20 folder, there is a chance that it could exist inside "**Details**" folder. If "abc.txt" existed on **Parent folder** then script should not look into child (**Details**) folder.

```
TargetDir->abc_01-01-20.txt
TargetDir->abc_01-02-20.txt
..
..
TargetDir->abc_12-31-20.txt
```

Here is the script I built

```
$Source = "\\Server01\root"
$SrcFile="abc.txt"
$GetSrcFile = Get-ChildItem $Source | Where-Object {$_.name -like "$SrcFile"}
$Destination = "C:\Target"
Copy-Item "$Source\$GetFile" "$Destination" -Force -
Confirm:$False -ErrorAction silentlyContinue
if(-not $?) {write-warning "Copy Failed"}
else {write-host "Successfully moved $Source\$SrcFile to $Destination"}
```

The problem is this script is not able to pull and append folder name to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing Source and Destination somewhat.
For this, you need to get the `abc.txt` files recursively and only when the direct parent folder's name is like a date, copy the file with a new name:

```
$Source      = 'C:\Source\rootdir'       # rootfolder where the subfolders with files are
$Destination = "\\Server01\Destination"  # path to where the files need to be copied

if (!(Test-Path -Path $Destination -PathType Container)) {
    $null = New-Item -Path $Destination -ItemType Directory
}

Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Recurse -Filter 'abc.txt' -File | 
    Where-Object {$_.DirectoryName -match '\\\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}$'} | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $newName = '{0}_{1}{2}' -f $_.BaseName, ($_.DirectoryName -split '\\')[-1], $_.Extension
        $target  = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath $newName
        try {
            $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $target -Force -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop
            Write-Host "File '$($_.Name)' copied to '$target'"
        }
        catch {
            Write-Warning "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. can you please take a look into modified question. hope it clears off all the confusions.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the time you spent. It works perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I think there are a few problems with your code.  You seem to be mixing up the source and destination.  Also, you are collecting the files into the variable $ScrFile but you're not iterating over it in such a way that you can determine the new name...

I worked this up very quickly and didn't test it but as a sample of how you might accomplish this it may be a starting point.

```
$Source      = "\\Server01\Destination"
$SrcFile     = "abc.txt"
$Destination = "C:\Source\rootdir"

# Note: this can be done with other ForEach permutations as well.

Get-ChildItem $Source -File | 
Where-Object{ $_.Name -match $SrcFile } |
ForEach-Object{
    # Get the name of the dir you found the file in:
    $ParentDirectory = Split-Path $_.DirectoryName -Leaf 
    
    #calculate a new file name including the directory it was found in:
    $NewFileName     = + $_.BaseName + $ParentDirectory + $_.Extension
    
    #Join the new name with the directory path you want top copy the file to
    $NewFileName     = Join-Path $Destination $NewFileName 
    
    # Finally try and copy the file.  Use try catch for more robust error handling
    Try{
        Copy-Item $_.FullName $NewFileName -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Successfully copied the file..."
    }
    Catch{
        # You can do a better job here...
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "There was an error copying the file!"
    }
}
```